# Return class mixin after checking a field of the class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I want to add a mixin class (MixinClass) to a class (A) that I already have but first I need to check if that class has a field (atr) or not. This is because class A can come from two different modules, in one there is a field attr and in the other there is not.

I've tried something like this, but I don't know how I can get the class A into the method

```
def check():
    class mixinClass(object):
        new_atr = None
    
    if hasatr(A, 'atr'):  # How can I check that the class has such a field?
        return mixinClass

class A(check()):
   ...
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to do and what output you want. You can't generally add a base to a class after it's been created. At best you can create a new subclass that has both the mixin and the original class as bases. But I'm not sure how that relates to your check for a specific attribute. What do you want to do if the attribute doesn't exist?

Comment: *class A can come from two different modules* - than why redefining it? Go on with that mixing class as standalone class and inside it check which `A` is used

Comment: The class already exists from other modules. What happens is that if I use a module from my company, the atr field is added and if I use one from third parties, the field does not exist. In some clients we have this module from third parties and others have ours. So I need to take into account that field for several operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically set the base class of a class with a metaclass, where you can put your desired logics of a conditional base class in the `__new__` method:

```
def mixin_if_hasattr(mixin, attr):
    class MixinIfHasattr(type):
        def __new__(metacls, name, bases, classdict):
            return super().__new__(
                metacls,
                name,
                bases + ((mixin,) if attr in classdict else ()),
                classdict
            )
    return MixinIfHasattr
```

so that:

```
class mixinClass:
    new_atr = None

class A(metaclass=mixin_if_hasattr(mixinClass, 'foo')):
    pass

class B(metaclass=mixin_if_hasattr(mixinClass, 'foo')):
    foo = None

print(A.__bases__)
print(B.__bases__)
```

outputs:

```
(<class 'object'>,)
(<class '__main__.mixinClass'>,)
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/JointShabbyBetaversion